# Как перемешать два списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Подскажите пожалуйста, как перемешать два списка?
Например из:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

получить:

```
['test1', 1, 'test2', 2, 'test3', 3]
```

Comment: `out` всегда должен выводить в такой последовательности?

Comment: это пример, так что не обязательно
но по порядку два словаря сливать не нужно

Comment: самый тупой вариант в лоб: цикл for и брать по элементу из каждого списка и добавлять в итоговый

Comment: в том то и прикол...for'ом иногда не идет, ошибку выдает

Comment: так надо прочитать ошибку и сделать выводы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ещё можно так:

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=['test1','test2','test3']

res = list(sum(zip(l2,l1),()))
print(res)

# ['test1', 1, 'test2', 2, 'test3', 3]
```

`sum` умеет "выпрямлять" коллекции, только нужно начальное значение подходящее указать, `()` - это пустой кортеж и `zip` тоже выдаёт кортежи.

Если порядок элементов в объединении списков не важен, то можно списки просто сложить:

```
print(l1 + l2)

# [1, 2, 3, 'test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

Comment: Это квадратичный алгоритм. Пусть и оригинальный.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я когда писал свой ответ, был уверен, что  кто-то предложит вариант с `sum`, но поленился написать предостережение :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну тогда надо через `chain` вон делать - и понятно и сложность должна быть нормальная )

Answer (score 7):

Если ключевым является **"перемешать"**, воспользуйтесь [random.shuffle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random

l1=[1, 2, 3]
l2=['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

l3 = l1 + l2
print(f'before: {l3}')

random.shuffle(l3)
print(f'after:  {l3}')
```

выведет:

```
before: [1, 2, 3, 'test1', 'test2', 'test3']
after:  ['test3', 2, 3, 'test2', 'test1', 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=['test1','test2','test3']

res = [x for y in zip(l2, l1) for x in y]
```

res:

```
['test1', 1, 'test2', 2, 'test3', 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще вариант c `chain`:

```py
from itertools import chain

l1=[1,2,3]
l2=['test1','test2','test3']

*res, = chain.from_iterable(zip(l2,l1))
print(res) 

# ['test1', 1, 'test2', 2, 'test3', 3]
```

или c `reduce`

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator

l1=[1,2,3]
l2=['test1','test2','test3']

res = reduce(operator.add, zip(l2,l1))
print(res)

# ('test1', 1, 'test2', 2, 'test3', 3)
```

Comment: С `chain` отличный вариант. А с `reduce` работает за квадрат. И `reduce(operator.add, ...)` равносилен `sum(..., ())`.